# How to get phone validator info to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm working with an API that includes validating a phone number and its information. Its works in the console log but will not display on screen itself.
in the (#info).html is suppose to be shown on screen but keeps returing as undeclared, been doing my best to change the wording without the use of dashes but hasn't helped.
Does anyone know what went wrong?

Thank you!

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://neutrinoapi-phone-validate.p.mashape.com/phone-validate", 
  data: { "country-code": country, number: number },
  success: function(data){ // if code works in console
      console.log( data );
      $('#info').html('international-number: ' + data.country + '<br>international-calling-code: ' + data.callingcode + '<br>localNumber: ' + data.localNumber + '<br>countryCode: ' + data.countryCode + '<br>is-Mobile: ' + data.mobile + '<br>type: ' + data.type); // show results on screen
     }, // found a way to display code without dashes

      error: function(jqXHR,textStatus){; // if code fails
      console.log( jqXHR );
      console.log( textStatus ); 
  },

      beforeSend: function(xhr){ // check for access key before
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-Mashape-Key', 'OnHOGDfyMLmshCe0o3CtIU6L4DDZp1sukFtjsn9LynwSBQbznL' );
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Accept', 'application/json' );
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
  }

        });

      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this issue. One includes using `[]` to access the property names that have dashes in them like so: `data['country-code']`.

But I noticed you've tried to access some properties that don't exist in the data. You can over come that by using a generic loop like so:

```
let output = '';
for (item in data) {
  output += item + ':' + data[item] + '<br>';
}
```

That simply builds up a string of each data element's name followed by its value and a `<br>` tag. Here it is in code:

```js
let country = 'us';
let number = '8881231234';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://neutrinoapi-phone-validate.p.mashape.com/phone-validate",
  data: {
    "country-code": country,
    number: number
  },
  success: function(data) { // if code works in console
    let output = '';
    for (item in data) {
      output += item + ':' + data[item] + '<br>';
    }
    $('#info').html(output); // show results on screen
  }, // found a way to display code without dashes

  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {; // if code fails
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
  },

  beforeSend: function(xhr) { // check for access key before
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 'OnHOGDfyMLmshCe0o3CtIU6L4DDZp1sukFtjsn9LynwSBQbznL');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='info'></div>
```